# Multiple toggle classes

Tags: angular, typescript

On a `<span>` element I have the following HTML:

```
<span (click)="openLeft()"></span>
```

A `@Component`'s method sets a `boolean` variable:

```
private isOpen: boolean;
openLeft() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
}
```

Finally, I need to set a class on another element just like we could do it in jQuery:

```
$('.collapse').toggleClass('in').toggleClass('hidden-xs').toggleClass('visible-xs');
```

So, I need to add/remove multiple classes depending on the `boolean` variable.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[ngClass]="{'collapse': isOpen, 'hidden-xs': isOpen, 'visible-xs': isOpen}"
```

or

```
[ngClass]="isOpen ? ['collapse', 'hidden-xs', 'visible-xs'] : []"
```